# Firebase PHP Data Submission - arrayValue, mapValue

Tags: php, arrays, google-cloud-firestore, mapping

I am trying to push data to a firestore DB using PHP and the Google apis.

Inside the documentation and examples I have seen around the web, I am able to use `mapValue` and `arrayValue` when sending data.

The example I am using is as follows:-

```php
[
    "orderName" => [
        "stringValue" => "Gbeila Aliu Wahab"
    ],
    "orderLocationName" => [
        "stringValue" => "Accra Mall Limited"
    ],
    "orderTotalAmount" => [
        "doubleValue" => 150.5
    ],
    "orderDescription" => [
        "stringValue" => "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry"
    ],
    "orderLocationGeoPoints" => [
        "geoPointValue" => (object) [
            "latitude" => 5.5557, 
            "longitude" => -0.1963
        ]
    ],
    "orderStatus" => [
        "stringValue" => "NotAssigned"
    ],
]
```

This works perfectly fine, but when I attempt to send an object or an array I get the following error returned to me:-

```
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"map_value\" at 'document.fields[0].value': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.",
```

when attempting to map the value using the following code:-

```
"orderName" => [
    "mapValue" => ["Gbeila Aliu Wahab", 123]
]

// or

"orderName" => [
    "arrayValue" => [
        "first" => [
            "stringValue" => "test"
        ], 
        "second" => [
            "stringValue" => "test123"
        ]
    ]
]
```

I have tried many variations to try to get this to work.

How am I supposed to be using the `mapValue` and `arrayValue` I can see a lot of mentions regarding the value option but I cannot see any examples on how to use the.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Payload to your array or map you're generating is incorrect as per [the documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/Value) You need to wrap your actual data (to store) under `values` key, your final array should be:

```php
["orderName" => ["arrayValue" => ["values" => [["stringValue" => "test"], ["stringValue" => "test123"]]]]]
```

Similarly your `mapValue` should be

```php
["orderName" => ["mapValue" => ["fields" => ["field1" => ["stringValue" => "Gbeila Aliu Wahab"]]]]]
```

Also, you can play with other data mapper via [this package.](https://github.com/ahsankhatri/firestore-php)